# Вопрос по сортировке

Tags: python

Я не понимаю как выстроить логику сортировки в данном задании, при том что нужно чтобы работало на разных значениях `ticket_types`, `user_tickets`

Пример:

*Input:*

```
ticket_types = ('Ж', 'К', 'З')

user_tickets = ['З', 'К', 'К', 'З', 'З', 'З', 'Ж', 'К', 'Ж']
```

*Output:*

```
['Ж', 'Ж', 'К', 'К', 'К', 'З', 'З', 'З', 'З']
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, так. Главное подобрать правильный ключ сортировки:

```py
ticket_types = ('Ж', 'К', 'З')
user_tickets = ['З', 'К', 'К', 'З', 'З', 'З', 'Ж', 'К', 'Ж']
sort_dict = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(ticket_types)}
print(sorted(user_tickets, key=lambda x: sort_dict[x]))
```

Вывод:

```
['Ж', 'Ж', 'К', 'К', 'К', 'З', 'З', 'З', 'З']
```

Можно было бы и не делать словарь для сортировки, но если данных будет много, этот вариант будет работать очень медленно:

```py
print(sorted(user_tickets, key=lambda x: ticket_types.index(x)))
```

Ещё вариант, через цикл в цикле:

```py
print([i for i in ticket_types for j in user_tickets if i == j])
```

Comment: проблема в том что до изучения словарей и enumerate с лямбдой я еще не дошёл и боюсь что намёк на то, что надо как то отсортировать без них

Comment: Ну тогда делайте цикл в цикле - по кортежу и по списку. И добавляйте в новый список по совпадению переменных обеих циклов. Я добавил код в виде спискового сокращения. Можете его переделать в обычные циклы.

Comment: спасибо большое)